# how can i deal with controlled and uncontrolled input in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form field shown in the picture below
[image]
The product field is a search field with suggestions when the user clicks the suggested option other form fields are filled automatically, the user can also override what has been filled automatically let's say **price**. On successful completion of the form, the details are added to a table. Now I'm facing a challenge when the user cancels the process after an autofill it doesn't override the previous values and this happens when I'm using the defaultValue attribute.
So I have tried using a value attribute and an onChange handler I can only type in the fields before an autofill meaning the user can not change fields like price after an autofill so how best can I tackle my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an approach that is using vanilla javascript to interact with the form fields.
example

```
const drug_details_from = React.useRef(null);
const [inputEl, setInputEl] = React.useState([]);

const handleSearchSelect = (values) => {
    const { form, qty, sellPrice, str, suppQty } = values;

    inputEl[1].value = qty;
    inputEl[2].value = formatAsMoney(sellPrice);
    inputEl[4].value = "1";
    inputEl[5].value = form;
    inputEl[7].value = suppQty;
    inputEl[8].value = "S";
 };
```